# Непонятная смена цвета шрифта ListView

Tags: java, android, listview

Здравствуйте. После того, как один очень добрый человек предложил мне прописать `mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(@кол-во экранов);` мои предыдущие проблемы исчезли. Но появилась одна небольшая, но назойливая проблема: после смены адаптера у `ListView` цвет шрифта внутри него стал меняться на белый.

Т.е. ситуация выглядит так: я заполняю `ListView` элементами из первого списка, потом, по нажатию клавиши, я меняю у этого `ListView` адаптер, вставляя в него второй список. Затем я по этой же клавише возвращаюсь к первому списку, но теперь у `ListView` шрифт стал белым. Если добавить в него него новый элемент, то все возвращается в свое нормальное состояние.

Создавать кастомный адаптер для `ListView` для ручной смены шрифта не особо хочется. Надеюсь, кто-то уже сталкивался с такой проблемой. Заранее благодарю за ответ.

Comment: Покажите код инициализации адаптеров. Скорее всего вы там опечатались.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб спасибо за подсказку. Действительно опечатался - брал не тот Context. Извиняюсь за беспокойство.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решена: взял случайно не тот Context при создании адаптера для ListView.

Comment: Если проблема решена - помечайте вопрос как закрытый.

Comment: @DroidAlex не могу, к сожалению, принять свой ответ в течение 2 дней.